# jupyterhub - How to install packages persistently?

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I have installed the JupyterHub docker image on my server, which automatically creates and launches jupyter notebook containers for each user who logs in: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub

Inside this personal container, I can use pip/conda to install extra packages. However, whenever the host machine reboots, the container has to be recreated and the installed packages are lost.

Is there a good solution for making this persistent? I suppose the installed packages could be mounted as some kind of persistent volume (like the user data already is), but with little Docker experience I wouldn't know how to set that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if [official Jupyter documentation on user environments](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/user-environment.html#allow-users-to-create-their-own-conda-environments) helps.
I've copied the text from the link below:

> ### Allow users to create their own conda environments
>
> Sometimes you want users to be able to create their own conda
>   environments. By default, any environments created in a JupyterHub
>   session will not persist across sessions. To resolve this, take the
>   following steps:
>
> Ensure the `nb_conda_kernels` package is installed in the root
>   environment (e.g., see [Build a custom Docker image with repo2docker](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/repo2docker.html#r2d-custom-image))
>
> Configure Anaconda to install user environments to a folder within
>   `$HOME`.
>
> Create a file called `.condarc` in the home folder for all users, and
>   make sure that the following lines are inside:
>
> ```
> envs_dirs:
>    /home/jovyan/my-conda-envs/
> ```
>
> The text above will cause Anaconda to install new environments to this
>   folder, which will persist across sessions.